# Automatic migrations doesn't work [EF Core]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to automate migrations in my project so added a 2 lines

```
_context.Database.Migrate();
_context.Database.EnsureCreated;
```

But i can't see any updates in my database. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Automatic migration has been removed from EF Core. This feature is not present in EF Core 2.0. There is no plan to add this feature to EF. Microsoft thinks it benefits is less than its drawbacks.

There are 2 methods in EF Core 2.0 related to migration. `Database.Migrate()` and `Database.EnsureCreated()`. Neither of them are a complete migration.

`Migrate()` does not add or create a migration. It only checks if any not-applied migrations exists or not. If yes, then updates the database based on them.

`EnsureCreated()` creates the database based on the models in the project. But it does not do this in the migration way. Actually no migrations are needed by this method. Disadvantage of this method is that a database created by it, can not be updated in future by any migrations. Indeed this method is added to EF to help people create projects fast in MVP style.

**Conclusion:** First add migration and then do update database ( Database.Migrate())